# How can I display these posts in ascending order?

Tags: posts

I am trying to display some posts in ascending order beginning with the first created and ending with the most recently created post. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$numofmebers = '-1';
if ( empty($_GET['page_id_all']) ) $_GET['page_id_all'] = 1;
    $count_post = 0;
        query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post_type' => 'coach-instructor' ,'post_status' => 'publish') );
        while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
            $count_post++;
        endwhile;
            if ( $node->instructor_pagination == "Single Page" ) {$node->instructor_page_num = -1;}
            query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => "$node->instructor_page_num", 'paged' => $_GET['page_id_all'], 'post_type' => 'coach-instructor' ,'post_status' => 'publish') ); 
        $counter_news = 0;
        while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
        $counter_news++;
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID );
        $coach_istructor_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_coach_istructor_meta", true);
            if ( $coach_istructor_meta <> "" ) {
                $xmlObject_author = new SimpleXMLElement($coach_istructor_meta);
                    $about = $xmlObject_author->about;
                    $specialism = $xmlObject_author->specialism;
                    $qualifications = $xmlObject_author->qualifications;
                    $philosophy = $xmlObject_author->philosophy;
                    $contact = $xmlObject_author->contact;
            }
            else {
                $about = '';
                $specialism = '';
                $qualifications = '';
                $philosophy = '';
                $contact = '';
            }
?>
```

Comment: Ascending or descending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that query_posts is best avoided as it has negative effects on the main loop.  A better approach would be a new instance of WP_Query or changing the query arguments for the main loop.

To get the order you want, try adding the following to your args:

```
array( 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post_type' => 'coach-instructor' ,'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked. I'm still learning PHP and operating within the Wordpress framework. This will help me in the future as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
$orde = ('orderby','date');
$ordr = ('order','DESC');
$query = array(
    'post_type' => array('posts_per_page'),
    'orderby'   => $orde,
    'order'     => $ordr
);
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! The parameters you are passing to the query are invalid. `orderby` can be an array, but in that case the "sort column" (precisely the value denoting the column) must be a key in the array, not a value.
Using an array in `orderby` should look like this: `$args = array( "orderby" => array("date"=>"DESC") )`.